# Laravel Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "1" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

No `join`, estou passando um valor direto, e o Laravel está tentando "ler" esse valor como se fosse uma tabela.

```
function ($join) {

    $join
       ->on('e.pee_fk_pes_codigo', '=', 'p.pes_codigo')
       ->on('e.pee_padrao', '=', '1');
});
```

Comment: +1 Esse problema acontecia direto comigo. Essa pergunta vai ajudar muita gente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Uso de `DB::Raw()`

A classe `JoinClause` (usada internamente dentro da `Closure`, que você chamou em `join`, pelo Laravel) por padrão espera valor com o nome dos campos das tabelas relacionadas.

Para usar um número, você pode usar `DB::raw()`. Assim:

```
function ($join) {

    $join
        ->on('e.pee_fk_pes_codigo', '=', 'p.pes_codigo')
        ->on('e.pee_padrao', '=', \DB::raw('1'));
})
```

`DB:raw` fará com que o Laravel aceite uma expressão SQL ser passada como parâmetro de `on`.

## Uso do `Where`

Em uma outra forma, a qual creio ser a mais indicada, você também poderá usar a clausula `where` ao invés de `on`:

```
function ($join) {

    $join
        ->on('e.pee_fk_pes_codigo', '=', 'p.pes_codigo')
        ->where('e.pee_padrao', '=', '1');
})
```

Veja como o resultado é compilado em SQL:

```
$sqlString = Usuario::join('niveis', function ($j) { 

    $j->on('niveis.id', '=', 'usuarios.nivel_id')
       ->where('niveis.id', '=', 4); 
       
})->toSql();

 echo $sqlString;
```

Resultado:

```
select * from 
    `usuarios`

inner join 
    `niveis` on `niveis`.`id` = `usuarios`.`nivel_id` 
    and `niveis`.`id` = ?
```

Comment: Qual é o motivo do -1? Poderia explicar, para eu poder melhorar os detalhes da resposta?